# Timestamp in chrome extension notification

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications, timestamp

My data is retrieved from  a json file to display the chrome extension notification. I want to include timestamp in my notification.

Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You must searching for `timestamp`. check notification options @ https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-notification-timestamp

Comment: I want to include timestamp inside chrome notifications create method..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @KshamaJain then why don't you add current time in `message` along with your JSON data.?